# Calling c# events from javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Could you please tell me if I can call a C# event or method from javascript code in an ASP.NET web application?

Comment: If you're talking about running some C# on your server from a browser, you can do that with an ajax call from client to server.  If you're talking about something else, please explain as there is no C# in the browser.

Comment: You can easily put the method in a  web service and call that method using a AJAX call, or use can use Page methods.

Comment: I found the answer by myself in time and it can be done - jquery can understand asp.net controls and jquery is actually javascript. not sure about events and methods but this is still useful. thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly execute a C# Event or Method. You can hit an endpoint via AJAX. This could be an ASP.NET MVC Controller or an .ashx handler.

Alternatively you can look at implementing something like SignalR, which via its Hubs, allows you to do magical things from javascript (and from the server, push notifications and things of that sort.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. C# is executed in the server side while javascript is execute in client side (browser).

Answer (score 0):

As I have pointed previously:

Example using Page methods: http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx
http://sappidireddy.wordpress.com/2008/03/31/how-to-call-server-side-function-from-client-side-code-using-pagemethods-in-aspnet-ajax/

Example using AJAX: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/250582/Getting-Started-with-jqChart-HTML5-jQuery-Chart-Pl

Answer (score 0):

Yes one can call `C# Method` from `javascript` using `ajax` in `asp.net webforms` also can do that in `asp.net MVC`

for example here is `web forms` example

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (response) {
             alert(response.d);
         },
         failure: function (response) {
             alert(response.d);
         }
     });
 });
</script>
```

and new code behind `c# method`

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData()
{
    return "This string is from Code behind";
}
```

Output looks like this 
[image]
 [image]